# what's the meaning of [‘ + str(param) +’] in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have encountered the code below when I’m learning about regex in python.
It’s a regex version of strip().

```
import re

def REstrip(text, param=' '):
    mo = re.compile(r'^([' + str(param) + ']*)(.*?)([' + str(param) + ']*)$')
    result = mo.search(text)
    if (result != None):
        print(result.group(2))


text = input("Please input the text: ")
param = input("Please input the param: ")
REstrip(text, param)
```

Output:

```
Please input the text: 11221
Please input the param: 11
22
```

What’s the meaning of `[' + str(param) + ']`(what’s the characters`' +  + '` in square bracket stand for?)

Comment: You're confusing the regex pattern with the Python code used to build it. Those `+`s are just concatenating strings to pass to `re.compile`.

Comment: I think `+` is just for concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this up a bit, for example:

```
prefix = '(['
suffix = ']*)'

expr = prefix + str(param) + suffix

mo = re.compile('^' + expr + '(.*)' + expr + '$')
```

So as you see that's not `+ +` between square brackets, just two string literals happen to end with `[` and begin with `]`.

Also, a pro tip: injecting an arbitrary string into a regex is not quite safe, so you may want to use `re.escape(str(param))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It means convert the "param" value that was passed to the function to a literal string data type and use it as part of the regular expression being evaluated. The plus (+) signs are concatenating strings together.